# Rails remote form throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form

```
<%= form_for([@group, lesson], remote: true) do |f| %>
            <tr id='<%= lesson.id%>' >
                <td><%= f.text_field :time %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :day %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :subject %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :teacher %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :room %></td>
                <td><%= f.submit 'Update'%></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [lesson.group, lesson], remote: true,method: :delete%></td>
            </tr>
        <%end%>
```

The controller

```
def update

@lesson = @group.lessons.find(params[:id])

@lesson.update_attributes(params[:lesson])

respond_to do |format|
    if @lesson
        format.html { redirect_to edit_group_path(@group), notice: 'Succesfully updated lesson' }
        format.js { render :json => @lesson, location: edit_group_path(@group) }
        format.json { render json: @lesson}
    else
        format.html { redirect_to edit_group_path(@group), notice:'Error!' }
        format.json { render json: @lesson }
    end
end
end
```

And JS

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('#new_lesson').on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
        $('.notice').append data
        ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
            $('.notice').append '<p>ERROR:'+error+'</p>'

    $(".edit_lesson").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
        $('.notice').append data
        ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
            $('.notice').append '<p>ERROR:'+error+'</p>'
```

The request goes fine, the entries get updated when I click the button. But it always throws the syntax error into '.notice':

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Other solutions found on the internet didn't help me

Comment: Isn't that a JavaScript error?

Comment: Your unexpected token is a syntax error in JS. Does it mention the line or file at all?

Comment: @RichPeck, doesn't mention the line. That's what confuses me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although we really need to see more information about the error (which file & what function is calling it), there could be a problem with this line in your controller:

```
format.js { render :json => @lesson, location: edit_group_path(@group) }
```

Firstly, why are you passing JSON to a JS request? If you want to have JSON data back, you'd typically use the datatype as JSON. If you've used JSON as an API or something, we'll have to look at that

Personally, I'd test this line:

```
format.js
```

then in `update.js.erb` I would use this:

```
alert(<%=j @lesson %>);
```

This will test to see if that line was the problem. If it was, it means you're going to have to adapt your system a little, but if you reply with the results, we can create a better answer

Comment: I will try that and respond as soon as I can. Thanks in advance

Comment: it worked! Thank you a lot, now I understand how to deal with such things.

Comment: No problem! If you have any other problems, please let me know

Comment: @RickPeck, while we are at it, is there a way to make the program throw not just the error, but also the document name and the line?

Comment: No problem! Rails is amazing - I'd love to help as many people as possible become proficient with it :)

Comment: @RickPeck, apparently the logs only state `Rendered lessons/create.js.erb (5.0ms)` and dont tell me about the error

Comment: The logs will explain any big time problems, like if your app crashes for a reason. However, if you're receiving "petty" errors (JS doesn't fire, etc), it's really part of the dev's job to sort them out. If you let me know the error specifically, I can help you if you like?

Comment: @RickPeck, nah, sorted it. Thanks for all the help again

Comment: Why I couldn't just response JSON to the AJAX (js) request?